# How can I get discount amount and grand total amount in mini cart ? (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, mini-cart

I would like to display discount amount and grand total (including discount) in mini cart with Magento 1.9 instead of sub total.

1. I didn't find out how to display discount (cart price rule without coupon)
2. Following this topic : [How do I get the discount amount in the minicart for 1.9?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46231/how-do-i-get-the-discount-amount-in-the-minicart-for-1-9)

I have been able to display the grand total including the discount... but it is not working for not logged in users.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load the quote first:

```
<?php
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quoteData = $quote->getData();
    $grandTotal = $quoteData['grand_total'];
?>
```

Then simply replace `$this->getSubtotal()` with `$grandTotal`.

To get the actual discount amount, you can use this:

```
$discountTotal = 0;
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use 'quote', you can use this code

```
$this->getData('grand_total');
```

In other case use

```
$quote->getData('grand_total');
```